# Bootstrap 3 carousel wont display correctly, or change images

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I can't seem to get the Bootstrap 3 carousel to turn images. None of it seems to work. This was originally done in CodePen but moved it all over to a text editor. I've looked all over for answers...

Here is the result...any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>


  <div id="carousel-home" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img/flower-21.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flower 1</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/flower12.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flower 2</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/flowers3.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flower 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-home" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-home" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4142kw50/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your provided JSFiddle, you are missing bootstrap Javascript library (bootstrap.js)

A tip when use bootstrap document, if you see anything in `Javascript` tab, it need `bootstrap.js`!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the `bootstrap.min.js` and `jquery` libraries for the carousel to work.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4142kw50/6/) (*expand the External Resources tab*)

The Bootstrap carousel doc is [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)